# SQL top N series for time-series data

Tags: sql, hive, apache-spark-sql, hiveql, impala

I am trying to build a sql query that will give me the top N series. To simplify we can say that top N will mean the biggest count(*) on the first day (or count(*) on entire series will be even better).

For exemple: 
I have X columns but only two that I am going to aggregate on : "color" and "date". The "color" column have multiple 100 variations, but I only want the top 10. For each of the 10 "colors" I want to have the count(*) of all the dates

With no ranking my query will look like this :

```
"select count(*), color, date from table group by color, date"
```

If I put a "order by + limit" it will just select the top segments, but not the top series.

Any idea?

thanks

PS; if that changes anything I am using hive/impala

EX input :

```
color  | date 
red    | 2016-01-01
red    | 2016-01-01
red    | 2016-01-01
red    | 2016-01-01
black  | 2016-01-01
black  | 2016-01-01
black  | 2016-01-01
red    | 2016-01-02
red    | 2016-01-02
black  | 2016-01-02
black  | 2016-01-02
black  | 2016-01-02
blue   | 2016-01-03
blue   | 2016-01-03
blue   | 2016-01-03
blue   | 2016-01-03
black  | 2016-01-03
red    | 2016-01-03
```

In this case, if I select only the "top 2 series", even if blue is the biggest on day three I only want to select black and red because they are the biggest "overall". Blue should be completely filter out of the results

Desired output

```
color  | date       | count
red    | 2016-01-01 |   4
black  | 2016-01-01 |   3
red    | 2016-01-02 |   2
black  | 2016-01-02 |   3
red    | 2016-01-03 |   1
black  | 2016-01-03 |   1
```

Comment: can share some sample data and output..

Comment: still facing issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be achieved usin cte and [window function](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+WindowingAndAnalytics) .

```
with temp as (
SELECT color ,date, COUNT(1) OVER (PARTITION BY color ,date ) as cont
from table)
select *  from temp order by cont
```

**Note:** update table with table name .