# How to filter data based on top values from a specific year in SQL?

Tags: sql, data-wrangling

Let's assume my data looks like this:

```
    year   person        cash
0   2020   personone     29
1   2021   personone     40
2   2020   persontwo     17
3   2021   persontwo     13
4   2020   personthree   62
5   2021   personthree   55
```

What I want to do is the following. I'd like to get the top 2 people comparing their `cash` based on `year` 2021. We can see that in 2021 `personone` and `personthree` are the top 2 people, then it can be ordered by `cash` in 2021. So the output I'm after is:

```
    year   person        cash
0   2020   personthree   62
1   2021   personthree   55
2   2020   personone     29
3   2021   personone     40
```

I've been trying a similar approach to the one described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40117401/sql-top-n-series-for-time-series-data) with no much luck.

Comment: Can you share your best coding attempt at this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `DENSE_RANK` here:

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *, DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY person ORDER BY cash DESC) dr
    FROM yourTable
    WHERE year = 2021
)

SELECT *
FROM yourTable
WHERE person IN (SELECT person FROM cte WHERE dr = 2);
```